# ValidationError at / ['“foo” is not a valid UUID.'] / Django admin authentication

Tags: django, python-3.x

I recently resetted my database and now Django raises the error `['“2” is not a valid UUID.']` when visiting any site on a logged in status.

The UUID is set as pk in my model and database and I am logged in properly with a superuser account.
I don't know **why** Django assigns `2` to the UUID variable?

[image]

**Model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
import uuid

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    DID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**View:**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

**Error:**

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\Dashex\Dashex\templates\base.html, error at line 42

“%(value)s” is not a valid UUID.
32  
33  <body>
34    {# Navigation Menu #}
35    <header>
36      {% block logo %}
37      <a href="/"><img id="logo" src="{% static 'images/logo.svg' %}" alt="dashex forex dashboard data"></a>
38      {% endblock %}
39      <div class="navigationWrapper">
40        <nav>
41          <ul>
42            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
43            <li><a href="/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
44            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></li>
45            {% else %}
46            <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a></li>
47            {% endif %}
48          </ul>
49        </nav>
50      </div>
51    </header>
52  

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'Wiki_app',
 'Dashboard',
 'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2309, in to_python
    return uuid.UUID(**{input_form: value})
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\uuid.py", line 169, in __init__
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')

During handling of the above exception (badly formed hexadecimal UUID string), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 92, in form_valid
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 99, in login
    if _get_user_session_key(request) != user.pk or (
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 58, in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2311, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(

Exception Type: ValidationError at /users/login/
Exception Value: ['“2” is not a valid UUID.']
```

**Database UUID entry for logged in user:**

[image]